# 'Axios' PUT request to server (URL failed)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, axios

I am fairly new to `Node.js/Express.js/Axios/MongoDb/Mongoose`, and it's my first time to ask in `stackoverflow`, so please correct me if I make any mistake in presenting the question.

I'm creating a website for novel, and I hope once the reader finish reading a chapter, his `readedChapterIds`(a property of user mongoose model) records the chapter ID that he just read.

First, I created the `get&put` route    `/:user_id`  in the folder `route/user.js` and `controller/user.js`, so users can edit their profiles in the website. I tested it and check it in `mongoDB` atlas to make sure that put route worked.
Second, I tested the `axios.get` in my `showChapter.js` to make sure that `axios` CDN did worked.
Third, I revised it as a put request. Here comes the problem.

```
    const currentUser = document.querySelector('#currentUser');
    const currentUserInString = currentUser.innerText;
    const chapterID = document.querySelector('#chapterID');
    const chapterIDInString = chapterID.innerText;

    const  readedChapterIds = { readedChapterIds: `${chapterIDInString}`}
    axios.put(`http://localhost:3000/${currentUserInString}`, readedChapterIds )
      .then(function (response) {console.log(response);})
      .catch(function (error) {console.log(error);});
```

and I got

PUT http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)
Error: Request failed with status code 404 at e.exports (axios.min.js:1:8675) at e.exports (axios.min.js:1:13500) at XMLHttpRequest.E (axios.min.js:1:7067)

I tried `/${currentUserInString}` `${currentUserInString}`
'http://localhost:3000/621832c2a7b93b0a95a1fb86' (the chapter ID I print using console.log).None of them work.
I read the axios docuemntation and all related question in stackoverflow, but find no solution.

My first question: how to fix my url problem?
My second question: should I use patch request instead of put request? I guess I should push the chapterID into the readedChapterIds array, so that he does not lose any reading record he had before.
or Maybe keep the axios.put but add     user.readedChapterIds.push(...readedChapterIds)    in the controllers/user.js ???

Thanks in advance. I appreciate any answer and keep trying.

Edit:

Here is my server side code:

```
router.put('/:user_id', catchAsync(users.updateUser));

module.exports.updateUser = async (req, res) => {
const { user_id } = req.params;
const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user_id, { ...req.body});
await user.save();
req.flash('succes', 'Successfully updated your User Profile!')
res.redirect(`/`)
}
```

Comment: perhaps the server code is wrong. Also, the fact that `http://localhost:3000/${currentUserInString}` results in `http://localhost:3000/` suggests `currentUserInString` is an empty string (a console.log would confirm that) - you may need to show the code for the server side endpoint you're trying to send the request to - it'd be unusual for it to be `/:id` but it's your design so who am I to judge

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with your url, Please double check if the url includes api keyword or something like that, Also please do check your request in Postman tool, from where you will get an idea

Comment: Thanks both. I printed currentUserInString and it's not empty.

Comment: I just update my questino with server side code. Now I'm watching youtube for postman introduction.

Comment: I send get request and I get an error. I guess I need to login first in postman. I'm figuring out how to login my webpage using postman.

Answer (score 0):

server side problem has been solved by the following code **:**

```js
module.exports.patchUser = async (req, res) => {
    // res.send('updating something')
    const { user_id } = req.params;
    const newRead = req.body.readedChapterIds;
    const user = await User.findById(user_id);
    user.readedChapterIds.push(newRead);
    console.log(user)
    await user.save();
    req.flash('succes', 'New Chapter Unlocks!')
    // res.redirect(`/`)
}
```

req.body wasn't readable due to the defauls headers, so I define the content type of the headers. In doing so, req.body is readable.

```
headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
```

Here is the whole picture of my browser side code:

```
let data = new URLSearchParams();
data.append('readedChapterIds', `${chapterIDInString}`)
axios({
    method: 'patch',
    url: `/${currentUserInString}`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data: data
})
.then((response) => console.log(response))
.catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Editted. I combined 2 answers into 1.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is solved using Content-Type

```
let data = new URLSearchParams();
  // check it more at https://www.itread01.com/content/1577199910.html
  data.append('readedChapterIds', `${chapterIDInString}`)
  axios({
        method: 'patch',
        url: `/${currentUserInString}`,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        data: data
    })
  .then((response) => console.log(response))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

Comment: If you solved the issue, you should post a complete answer

Comment: If you have a complete answer now, please consider deleting this one to clean up the page.